# Display block e Display None aparecem ao mesmo tempo

Tags: css, display

Estou tentando criar um dark mode para meu site, porém, os dois aparecem ao mesmo tempo e quando clico para alterar o theme da pagina, o icon errado some.

Gostaria que o icon sumisse e o outro icon assumisse.

HTML

```
<div class="mode">
    <input type="checkbox" name="change-theme" id="change-theme"/>
    <label for="change-theme">
        <i class="bi bi-toggle-on" onclick="changeVisibily()"></i>
        <i class="bi bi-toggle-off" onclick="changeVisibily()"></i>
   </label>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* Dark Theme */
.mode {
 margin-right: -25%;
} 

.bi {
    font-size: 1.9rem;
    color: #0080ff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.bi:hover {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.673);
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 10px rgb(0, 136, 255));
}

.light, .light header{
    background-color: rgb(176, 176, 176);
    color: black;
}

.light .bi-toggle-on {
    display: block;
}

.light .bi-toggle-off {
    display: none;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
const changeThemeBtn = document.querySelector("#change-theme")

changeThemeBtn.addEventListener("change", function (){
    document.body.classList.toggle("light")
});
```

Answer (score -3):

Tens que ter um estado inicial em que o ícon ON não está visível. Basta adicionar esta regra:

```
.bi-toggle-on {
    display: none;
}
```